# Java. Creating new class similar to List

Tags: java, class

[image: Structure]
I would like to create my own class, which had 3 fields. The first field - integer, the second would take objects (Strings, Lists), and the third would take integers. I do not understand two things.

1. How to organize the storage of variables. I need to write a method in which the Array or List will save these values​​? How to save in object values?
2. For second field. If the input is a String or a List so what Type is needed? and if I want to take as primitive types, then what? How to save object?

   > ```
   > public class Record {
   >    private int[] number;
   >    private int[] count;
   >    private Object[] code;
   >
   >    public void add(int newNumber, List<String> newCode, int newCount){
   >
   >      return;
   >    };
   >
   >    public void add(List<String> newCode, int newCount,){
   >
   >        return;
   >    };
   > ```

This doesn't work.

```
   Object nobj = new Object();
nobj = "ss";
```

Comment: For your first question: use `ArrayList` instead of plain `[]` arrays

Comment: ohh...seems like you understand something wrong in OOP...

Comment: @Andreas explain? SeniorJD why?)

Comment: @Eldar See Chris' answer below

Comment: see my answer please. or @Chris 's one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay. It appears to me that you've misunderstood the purpose of your class. You've written a class to simulate a single `Record`, but you've written `Record` to store many values.

**Let's re-arrange your class structure a little**

```
public class Record {
private int number;
private int count;
private Object code;

public Record(int number, int count, Object code)
{
     this.number = number;
     this.count = count;
     this.code = code;
}
```

Then you can create a class, to manage the interface between the `Record` class, so for example:

```
public class Storage
{
     List<Record> records;
     public Storage()
     {
         this.records = new ArrayList<Record();
     }

     public void addRecord(int number, int count, Object code)
     {
          records.add(new Record(number, count, code));
     }
}
```

That way, you're not messing about with lots of different arrays, which are horrible to try to keep track of, Everything is neatly wrapped up inside your objects.

**Your issue with the second attribute**

Now, it seems you want to store *anything* in this variable. This is somewhat more complex than your original problem, but I think that [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) will answer your problem for you. I won't write the code for you, but what I can do is give you a demonstration.

```
public class GenericExample<T>
{
     T object;

     public GenericExample(T object)
     {
         this.object = object;
     }
}
```

Okay, so what I've done here is simple. I've created a new class, `GenericExample`, and I've said that this class has a special type, `T`. This type is defined at run time, and means you can define plenty of different values. For example.

```
GenericExample<String> example = new GenericExample<String>("This is a string");
GenericExample<Object> example2 = new GenericExample<Object>(new Object());
```

See how you can define the type, and pass it in at run time? Now think about applying it to your class structure.

Comment: Few words, why it should be ArrayList not a HashList. What if my first field just number(serial number), then better take Map? HashMap?
And one more question on this topic, if i want create child of record, which have more fields, then i must create 2nd storage for other purpose?

Comment: No, actually you don't. Storage is of type `Record`, which means it also stores every child of `Record`. You can use a `HashList` if you want. I just used `ArrayList` as an example. I'm afraid I don't understand the rest.

Answer (score 1):

If you really do not need to create your own `List`, avoid that. Just create your own type of data and use it as a parameter for `List`:

```
public class Record {
    private int number;
    private int count;
    private Object code;

    // Constructors, setters and getters
};

List<Record> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```